# Error 400 when parsing variable to GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I have a basic react component that should render some dynamic data from my graphql db via react-apollo. I try to pass a content id to my query like so:

```
export default withApollo(graphql(
    gql`
            query ($postId: String!){
                blogPost (where: { id: $postId }){
                    title
                }
            }
    `,
    {
        options: {
            variables: {
                postId: "cjju54kgfl4r6095353zn6us1"

            },
            props: ({data}) => ({data})
        }
    })(Post))
```

This example gives me a 400 error on the server

However, it works like this:

```
export default withApollo(graphql(
    gql`
        query {
            blogPost (where: { id: "cjju54kgfl4r6095353zn6us1" }){
                title
            }
        }
    `,
    {
        options: {
            props: ({data}) => ({data})
        }
    })(Post))
```

I went through the whole Apollo docs and just can't figure out what im doing wrong here.

Here is the whole component in case that's helpful:

```
import PageLayout from '../layouts/main'
import ContentWrapper from '../layouts/contentWrapper'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import {graphql} from 'react-apollo'
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import withApollo from "../lib/withApollo";
import ErrorMessage from '../components/ErrorMessage'

const headerContent = {
    headline: 'Test',
    subHeadline: 'Test'
}

function Post({data: {variables, loading, error, blogPost}}) {
    if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading</div>
    }
    else if (error) {
        return <ErrorMessage message='Error loading posts.'/>
    }
    else {
        return (
            <PageLayout>
                <Header data={headerContent}/>
                <ContentWrapper>
                    <h1>{blogPost.title}</h1>
                    <p>{JSON.stringify(variables)}</p>
                </ContentWrapper>
            </PageLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default withApollo(graphql(
    gql`
            query ($postId: String!){
                blogPost (where: { id: $postId }){
                    title
                }
            }
    `,
    {
        options: {
            variables: {
                postId: "cjju54kgfl4r6095353zn6us1"

            },
            props: ({data}) => ({data})
        }
    })(Post))
```

I'm really stuck with this, thanks for helping out!

Logging `data.error` throws:

```
Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:34)
    at ObservableQuery.webpackJsonp../node_modules/apollo-client/core/ObservableQuery.js.ObservableQuery.currentResult (ObservableQuery.js:87)
    at Query._this.getQueryResult (Query.js:104)
    at Query.webpackJsonp../node_modules/react-apollo/Query.js.Query.render (Query.js:206)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13193)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13155)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:13824)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15863)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:15902)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:15942)
```

Comment: I removed my previous answer, since it wasn't useful. 

But I'm inclined to think this is an issue on the backend, processing the variables object sent in the request.

Can you share the POST request body sent to the server?

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out:

`$postId: String!` hast to be `$postId: ID`

thanks for helping, seems i got this basic GraphQL concept wrong.